# Blocking FTP Brute Force Attack with Snort

Tags: snort

I am trying to become familiar with Snort, and for this reason, I have set three VMs. A Kali, a windows machine with XAMPP and Ubuntu where I installed Snort.

I believe I have Snort running in Afpacket Inline mode. Whenever Snort starts it says " Enabling inline operation-Running in IDS mode"

On the windows machine, there is an FTP server running with a user "John" and Pass: 123456.
I am attacking the server with Ncrack on Kali, and it is able to find the password in around 2 minutes. I am trying to block the attack and be able to distinguish between a real user (me trying to log in on the host machine) and the attacker. My plan is to make a rule that goes like this:  "If the server receives more than 5 attempts to login in 1 second then drop the packet/attempt."

I have searched a lot, I have spend a good amount of hours this week not being able to find the correct rule.

Do you have any tips? any rules I should try? Am I doing something that wrong? Thanks

What I have tried until now:

> alert tcp any any -> $HOME_NET 21 (msg:"Incoming FTP connection"; flags:S; sid:10000010;)
> #alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 22 (msg: "Incoming SSH Connection"; GID:1; sid:10000012; rev:001;)
> #drop tcp $HOME_NET 21 -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:"FTP Bad login"; content:"530 Login"; nocase; flow:from_server,established;
> classtype:bad-unknown; threshold: type both, track by_dst, count 5,
> seconds 5; sid:491; rev:5;)
>
> #alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 21 (msg:"Possible FTP brute force attack"; metadata:service ftp-data; session:binary;
> sid:10000011; rev:001;)
>
> #drop tcp $HOME_NET 21 -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:"FTP Brute Force Attack Attempt"; content:"530 Login or password incorrect!"; nocase;
> flow: stateless; threshold: type both, track by_dst, count 3, seconds
> 1; sid:10000012;rev:1;)
>
> #drop tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 21 (msg:"FTP Incoming Connections"; flags:S; threshold: type both, track by_src, count 3, seconds 1; sid:100000011; rev:1;)
>
> #drop tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 21 ( msg:"PROTOCOL-FTP USER overflow attempt"; flow:to_server,established; content:"USER",nocase;
> isdataat:100,relative; pcre:"/^USER(?!\n)\s[^\n]{100}/smi";
> metadata:policy max-detect-ips drop,ruleset community;
> reference:bugtraq,1>
>
> #drop tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 21 ( msg:"PROTOCOL-FTP PASS overflow attempt";flow:to_server,established; content:"PASS",nocase; isdataat:100,relative; pcre:"/^PASS(?!\n)\s[^\n]{100}/smi"; metadata:policy max-detect-ips drop,ruleset community reference:bugtraq,1>
>
> #drop tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 21 ( msg:"PROTOCOL-FTP ProFTPD username sql injection attempt"; flow:to_server, established; content:"|25 27|",fast_pattern,nocase; content:"USER";pcre:"/USER\s*[^\x0d]+\x25\x27/smi"; metadata:policy max-detect-ips drop; reference:>
> #drop tcp $HOME_NET 21 -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:"FTP login failure"; content: "530 Login "; nocase; flow:from_server,established; threshold: type both,track by_dst,count 10,seconds 15; sid:10000011; )
> #drop tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET 21 (msg:"FTP login success"; content: "PASS"; nocase; offset:0; depth:4; content: "|0a|" ;
> within:3; flow:from_client,established; threshold: type both,track
> by_dst,count 10,seconds 15; sid:10000012; )
>
> reject tcp $HOME_NET any -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:
> "BLEEDING-EDGE-SCAN Potential FTP Brute-Force attempt";
> flow:from_server,established; content:"530 "; pcre:
> "/^530\s+(Login|User)/smi"; classtype:unsuccessful-user; threshold:
> type threshold,track by_dst, count 5, seconds 30; sid:2002383; rev:3;)

> #alert tcp $HOME_NET 21 -> $EXTERNAL_NET any (msg:"ET SCAN Potential FTP Brute-Force attempt"; flow:from_server,established; dsize:<100;
> content:"530 "; depth:4; pcre:"/530\s+(Login|User|Failed|Not)/smi";
> classtype:unsuccessful-user; threshold: type both, track by_dst, count 5, seconds 30; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/2002383; reference:url,www.emergingthreats.net/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/sigs/SCAN/SCAN_FTP_Brute_Force; sid:2002383; rev:11;)

Most of the above bring logs, and I think some blocks, but not what I am really looking for.

Comment: I also tried snortban, Snortsam and Fail2ban  but still didn't find a solution.